# Any idea on what this component is?

Tags: rf, identification, surface-mount, gps

It's an 0402 sized component. Measures about 50 milliohms out of circuit. I also measured it with a cheap LCR meter and it shows -47nH. Capacitance measures 350mF. So I'm pretty sure it's a jumper.  It's weird that it's on an antenna GPS feed line coming in from the middle right.

It looks like it's shorting the signal to ground. The component is half green half black and there are a few others of these on the circuit.

**If it is a jumper why is it shorting the signal to ground?**

[image]

Comment: Can you make the image any more pixelated? one can almost see something

Comment: @PlasmaHH uploaded new image.

Comment: 350mF? Call a newspaper, you've just discovered a 0402 SuperCap that somehow nobody ever reported on.

Comment: @Asmyldof  LOL. Yeah I did say it was a cheap LCR meter.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't 350nF?

Answer (score 12):

50 mOhm resistance, 47nH inductance? Its probably an inductor. Murata make some thick film inductors in a green package with a black stripe. Its probably one of these: http://psearch.en.murata.com/inductor/product/LQG15HS10NJ02%23.pdf

Assuming the pin is the antenna then having an inductor feed into another inductor down to ground is a common circuit topology.

Comment: The op said -47 nH not +47 nH.

Answer (score 3):

The LCR meter I've used provides a single frequency stimulus (current or voltage) and measures the magnitude and phase of the response (voltage or current).  Then it makes an assumption about the circuit, and calculates the one combination of component values which will match the response with the stimulus.

For example when measuring an inductance, it assumes that it is a resistor in series with an inductor.  If actual circuit has current leading voltage (for inductors, current lags voltage), then the meter will report a negative inductance, even though that's nonsensical.

You need to disconnect one end of the component from the circuit.  Otherwise you're measuring the device you're concerned with in parallel with the rest of the circuit.

Comment: He said he already measured it out of circuit.